# Search for a Document by its Name using SharePoint Lists.asmx GetListItems

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(@"<Where><Lt>");
sb.AppendLine(@"<FieldRef Name=""FileRef"" /><Value Type=""Text"">momo.txt</Value>");
sb.AppendLine(@"</Lt></Where>");

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
ndQuery.InnerXml = sb.ToString();

XmlNode resultsElement1 = listsProxy.GetListItems("Documents", "", ndQuery,
                                                  null, null, null, "");
```

But it returns all the Documents any Idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileRef` fields contains the server-relative URL to the document, something like this "`/Subsite/Lists/ListName/DocumentName`". If you provide only the file name (e.g. `mono.txt`), neither `Lt` or `Eq` should work.

To fix the problem, you might try:

1. Use `Eq` with the server-relative URL instead of file name.

```
sb.AppendLine(@"<Where><Eq>");  
sb.AppendLine(@"<FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/SubSite/Lists/Documents/momo.txt</Value>");  
sb.AppendLine(@"</Eq></Where>");
```

1. Or you might use `<Contains>` operator (CAML does not have <`EndsWith>` operator).

```
sb.AppendLine(@"<Where><Contains>");  
sb.AppendLine(@"<FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/momo.txt</Value>");  
sb.AppendLine(@"</Contains></Where>");
```

Then looping over the returned results, and remove items which does not end with "`/mono.txt`".

In addition, if you care about document name without extension, you could you `BaseName` instead of `FileRef` field.

Answer (score 4):

Currently your query is for items where the name value is less than `momo.text` rather than equal to it. Therefore change `Lt` to `Eq`.